# Magento 1.7.0.2 - Subtotal and grand total doubled in cart

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, cart

A few customers have complained that they are getting subtotal and grand total prices that are double of what they should be. After some tests, I've found that when a user adds a product to cart, go to checkout, then changes his mind and removes the item from the cart - the next time he will add a product to the cart, the subtotal and grand total prices will get doubled. It happened only in IE and Firefox, not in Chrome.

I've found this post: https://web.archive.org/web/20150227130454/http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/227560/P0/

I've checked the DB table sales_flat_quote_address and saw there were quote ids that had more than one shipping and billing address.

I implemented the solution that is shown in this post: https://web.archive.org/web/20150227035906/http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/227560/P15/#t393997

and the price is no longer getting doubled in the situation I described above.

The problem is that since this fix I still get occasionally a complaint from customers about the price being doubled and I see the same situation in the DB table sales_flat_quote_address, but I can't reproduce this issue so I don't know when it happens.

Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same problem. I also don't know what the root cause of the issue is, but have an idea for why you are still seeing some stragglers after your code change.

The `init()` method is called in the `CartController::indexAction()`. So it only runs when the customer loads the cart page. If you have some kind mini-cart widget on your site--anything that shows the current subtotal but isn't the full-on cart page--then the subtotal will still be double in the mini-cart whenever there are duplicate addresses. If that's the case, it should be fixed as soon as the customer goes to the cart page.

Comment: It may also be that they have a cart saved from a period of time that this issue was more prevalent.

Comment: Except that the double-address would be cleared as soon as they hit the cart page.

Answer (score 1):

Look at settings -> shipping -> Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses and Maximum Qty Allowed for Shipping to Multiple Addresses

Set them **to NO and 0.**

Comment: Worth a read as well: http://www.daveboyce.com/double-order-totals-in-magento/

Comment: The URL does not work.

Comment: Updated URL: http://daveboyce.com/?p=350

Comment: Not working neither. Luckily the internet archive got our back: https://web.archive.org/web/20161230082727/http://www.daveboyce.com/double-order-totals-in-magento/